# Расшифровать значение программы

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int* form(int&n) { 
   n = 10 + 19 % 10;
   int*a = new int[n];
   *a = 19; 
   for(int i = 1;i < n;i++){
      *(a + i) = *(a + i - 1) + 1;
}
return a;
}
int main(){
int *a, n, i, *p;
a = form(n);
 
for ( p = a+n, i=1; i <= n; i++ )
{
    *(p-i) *= (int)sqrt(19);
}
```

Всем привет! Есть такой фрагмент программы, он что-то означает, возможно какие то определенные математические действия, надо его расшифровать, у меня что-то вообще не получается понять что это такое. Надеюсь на вашу помощь, буду очень благодарен всем за помощь.

Comment: Да без проблем :)

    `int main() { int * a = new int[19]; for(int i = 0; i < 19; ++i) a[i] = 76+4*i;` 

Годится?

Comment: @Harry, спасибо, а a[i] = 76+4*i; это вы откуда взяли?

Comment: Посмотрел, что делает ваш код...

Comment: Аа, ну не очень понятно если честно, ладно, я хотел бы у вас еще спросить, в строке int* form(int&n)
это тоже самое что и int *form(int &n), если с пробелами?

Comment: Потому что пробелы не являются в данном случае синтаксически важными. Компилятор понимает, что `int`, `&` и `n` — три разные лексемы. Это `intn` и `int n` — разные вещи :)